# How to get started with phase locked loops?

Tags: control-system, simulink

I was given a project to simulate a phase locked loop system.  So far, I have only understood the very basic idea of how it works (not the maths behind it.) I want to play around with testing each component at a time in Simulink, but I want to understand how to calculate the parameters values. The number of parameters in the mathwork tutorials are overwhelming. Could someone suggest a book that would help understand the theory with some basic examples?

Comment: You appear to be falling foul of site rules in asking for recommendations: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete.*. Additionally, you are also falling foul to the site rule about asking for opinions: *This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.*

Comment: https://www.nxp.com/files-static/rf_if/doc/app_note/AN535.pdf https://www.ti.com/lit/an/scha003b/scha003b.pdf?ts=1670953530683&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.be%252F

Comment: https://nl.mathworks.com/help/msblks/phase-locked-loop.html?s_tid=CRUX_topnav

Comment: Rima, The ARRL (American Radio Relay League) comes out with a new large edition of a long-running book they are responsible for. It does a yeoman's job of discussing PLLs, distinctions between different topologies and how to choose, and ranges of applications for them. The book is quite cheap, especially when "bought used." And it doesn't just hammer you with math trying to get points across. It does try to talk to people who are not familiar with the concepts. ARRL also has a lot of supplementary materials available, as well.

Comment: Another reference, this time Analog Devices tutorial, MT-086, Fundamentals of Phase Locked Loops.  https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-086.pdf  It has many references at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A PLL is simple at 1st in concept.

“Make Everything as Simple as Possible, but not Simpler.”
Albert Einstein

Read this from TI Take your time. It's 497 pages
https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/snaa106c/snaa106c.pdf

---

Use a PLL chip, with a signal. That gets limited to a logic signal at the same frequency that your stable or not so stable VCO can track with a phase error voltage that is integrated to get a DC voltage that operate at that frequency.

There are 2 fundamental types of mixers or detectors.

**Phase Detector type** Type 1

These have low jitter but a limited Capture Range of frequency error limited by the integrator low pass filter reducing gain error. These tend to be XOR gates. But there are also linear types. They are also frequency doublers since it locks out of phase by 90 degrees, so there are transitions from both signal and clock.  The VCO in PLL ICs can be internal with a high (MHz) or Hz/Volt gain but also large frequency error requiring more BW and more noise thus lower SNR as the LPF acts as a BPF to noise.

**Phase/Freq Type Detector** Type 2

These use D logic registers or similar to pulse the period of clock and data cycles to assert a binary output to capture frequencies far from the target on the VCO.  The actual outputs are often tristate and then switch On for Pump up or switch low for Pump down the control voltage to an integrating cap to control the VCO.

To use the benefits of a Bode Plot and measure closedloop stability from a step error, we measure phase margin at unity gain frequency. Since there are two integrators an RC one and the phase detect which integrates frequency errors pulse by pulse to phase errors, you have a het to be stable 2nd order system. As in most closed loop servos the most stable are 1st order at unity gain so we accomplish this by inserting a series resistance with the Cap filter. then add a 10x small cap in parallel with the R if you need less jitter but possibly small overshoot on capture.

To make a frequency multiplier in a PLL you use a divider from the VCO to the (frequency) mixer or Phase detector.
To make a fractional N Synth one can imagine this multiplier with a divider outside the loop. But now these are all internal to PLL ICs.

Let me pull a simple PLL model from Falstad's Simulator which is far easier to learn than Simulink.

Type 2 detector
[image]
or
[image]

[FALSTAD SIM.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgTCAMB0l5YAsBOVb3oBzmpyBmARgDYlNlEBWMYwxEY%20ykSyFgUwFpDCAoQytkQkQJIYmxiovAMYtCEKZQXg4UUVwDsITjEyUUaTQgXJKxbTDh8ATvIhh8ESpuLgn68-F53lDxiyu4AFsYGDwVhFR%20LwA7oFujs5BNPSQvADmCcFMKchubOkASjqaisRs3JD0JIWiDIWwkMxg0MyNlHGiYJLIij050vEK2KkgwokhmSD41eBIM3NJ6unxE6LEQiLhhV2zNRUz1Bu78fjHO0eKQatXqmzrl%20kkhN2Sh4RBtdJ2YQds%20xO6kIUVki3%204NEfWBWlE0EQ%20EwdEI52IFTCx0itkhhGhgL%206nwyG8AEM7lJ1lIeKJmNxmCConCEUiaMhNJR8E4JJh8EzEcjUeikCIGd5wtoRkDJQoHiAAMoASQy0AAOgBnBUAO144vG2wC60B9AAagBhADy6oA9gBXAAuOsg2kpmz1bhl4xAZstaoAltrdQTvkHwp6ALIKgAe7Bs1vtvEjIEwimhPAlZk9dBApoANgBrdVa3iIAggMosRJqD1sXEAfRItcg9YRpGItdayBRYGMdHItDAyHwjaakEIte49eLpYCPRreMQaVU9bbTfwmhRTcow7HE74cjA5ihDkPBIe0E0XBBOkIsAX68gFQffScA8vaSafDOc1xx-d0Nu%20ILAeiQLOkWQSPM9AQcBKy8CUEH5OMQjYHUJYsCsUBtF03DuocOGqCh2Eiio%20HfLcEHfBR-5dBRAwUYc6QAGbXpWyEEcCbSYc0vDMaRKgUSorw3u0sCdHIpF4WhZE4DsURyQgXAoU0KDKGinasi4Bjslxo4%20CxQL0XUooRF00qHIZPw6FJeHltJxlTryiJMG4aI1KGoRjg2TYogYNC1luMA7p5DngNBmDYGubjnBAc7Lo2tYlsgmD%20du45jkO4TxWEja8IiDAgAAYq8vIMqI8DXoVNjsAAjja7CajIACevBAA)

[image]